# Magento 2 bin/magento not working as it should

Tags: magento2, php, cli

I've just installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.1.2 from composer. I've previously installed Magento 2 in a different directory completely fine and the commands all run as they should. This has only happened since I installed a new repo to a different directory that the CLI for Magento started to not work.

I'm running Magento 2 with the following:

- PHP 7.0.10
- MySQL 5.6
- Mac OS
- MAMP Pro 4
- Apache

I've tried:
Setting the correct permission
setting `bin/magento` file and folder to chmod executable.
chown to `my_username:admmin`

I have php setup perfectly fine in system $PATH. I've also noticed n98 does the same no errors/output just goes to a new line in the terminal.

If i run composer loads fine, if I run `php -v` loads php7 fine

I've been trying to fix this now for hours with no luck.

Comment: Command look like php bin/magento not bin/magento.

Comment: Sorry yes the commands I've tried are: bin/magento cache:clean and php bin/magento cache:clean I've also tried running it with the full path to my php version also with no joy

Comment: you have to add any error output or describe what happens if you execute bin/magento. It's impossible to solve the problem if you don't provide any information about the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply to the answers given, however none of these worked for me, I believe the problem was using MAMP.

I've uninstalled and setup brew services and it's now running fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found a problem inside the PHP error log. One directory was missed inside the vendor directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are in the root directory of your magento2 folder

   eg: `pc-user@xxxx-xxxxx:/var/www/html/magento2$`
2. sometimes using `php bin/magento` will cause an error like this

   `cache_dir "/var/www/html/magento2sample/var/cache/" is not writable` 
   So, try `sudo bin/magento` (sudo instead of php)
3. try running this cammand also
   `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2/`