# Magento 2 - bin/magento suddenly stopped working

Tags: magento2

If I execute `php bin/magento list` then nothing happens.

It stopped working after executing `composer update` and `grunt clean`

If I open the frontend I get

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/home/xxx/yyy/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'
> (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in
> /home/xxx/yyy/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
>
> Warning:
> require(/home/x/y/vendor/composer/../magento/services-connector/registration.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/x/y/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70

---

**Update**: I set permissions, but it still does not work:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Try to run composer install in magento root and if didn't work at <magento_dir>/update/

Comment: I tried `composer install` it did not helped.

Comment: In both root and <magento_dir>/update/? any erros?

Comment: Try this --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143307/magento-2-bin-magento-not-working-as-it-should

Comment: @YoYoRoshan, what exactly do you want me to try?

Comment: @RuiSilva, I don't get any errors when running `composer install` in both.

Comment: Try to check the permissions of the folders all the way in '/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'

Comment: @RuiSilva, I have set the permissions like seen in my updated question. Still not working.

Comment: You can try to delete vendor folder e download all again just in case, if that doesn't work I advise to contact cPanel and see what they can do, in a kick search didn't come with something useful unless try to contact them directly

Comment: cPanel is a software, how should I contact the software?

Comment: I deleted the vendor folder and executed `composer install` but it does still not work.

Comment: Try contact the provider or support at cPanel website. You can try to check that line and see if the path is right or even go to that path and check if the file is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that a new magento update is responsible for this mess.

> $ composer update Loading composer repositories with package
> information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Package
> operations: 0 installs, 3 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Updating composer/composer (1.10.8 => 1.10.9): Loading from cache
> - Updating magento/services-connector (1.0.5 => 1.0.6): Loading from cache

As you can see `magento/services-connector` received an update. This update removes the important file **registration.php**, for unknown reasons which then can't get loaded anymore:

> Warning:
> require(/home/x/y/vendor/composer/../magento/services-connector/registration.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/x/y/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
> on line 70

**Solution**: Revert the update by using old version again until they have fixed it (check on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29188#issuecomment-660132927)):

```
composer require magento/services-connector 1.0.5
```